# How to  increase the height of interval in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to increase the height of interval in full calendar , my events would be 15 minutes slots .But for now its very small section,really not able to see it clearly .I've tried with css,but  not worked out.Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just play with [contentHeight](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/contentHeight/) option to adjust for your needs.

See on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Doomsday/NCDXj/) example a contentHeight of 2500px and slotMinutes of 15.